# How to use sqlite in a WPF application(Entity Framework)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, system.data.sqlite

I am using sqlite database instead of sql server 2008 in my WPF project.

I am using Entity Framwork for performing CRUD operations.

Work perfectly fine in my machine.

But when I published and ran on other machine application doesn't work

The problem is that the application tries to connect to the database which doesn't exist on that machine.

```
<add name="PersonalExpenseDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=E:\sqlLite\db\PersonalExpenseDB.s3db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

As you can see datasource is referring to database file

```
data source=E:\sqlLite\db\PersonalExpenseDB.s3db
```

which was present on my machine but isn't on other machine.

So, naturally it doesn't find the database file on other machine and gives me error

My question is: How to make the database local to the application? i.e. when i publish the app, database file should be copied and made local to the application.

The error i get is

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Unable to open the database file at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum flags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption) at SqlLiteDatabase.List.Window_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised) at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args) at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e) at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent) at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root) at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork() at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks() at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget) at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget) at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow) at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox) at System.Windows.Window.Show() at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() at SqlLiteDatabase.MainWindow.button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Embed the .sdb file in your project (Copy always property), and make the path relative in the app.config

Comment: Can you give me an example as to how to make the path relative? I tried that but it makes while entity framework generates the data source property it takes the path "C:\sqlite\....", it should come something like "@App_Data\PersonalExpenseDB.s3db".. Please tell em if i can do this..

Comment: Try using the data directory substitution string (e.g. "Data Source=|DataDirectory|PersonalExpenseDB.s3db")

Comment: I tried that.. But still problem isn't solved completely.. Please visit   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3a3a4ba2-3323-4b3e-b1ee-2f7f8901d25b                     and reply back if you know tha answer.. Thanks...